# Do enemies drop EXP when converted into Harmless Takodachis?

Tags: holocure-save-the-fans

Normally when an enemy is defeated it will drop EXP. However, Ninomae Ina'nis has two skills (The Void and The Ancient One) that can convert enemies into Harmless Takodachis before they are defeated.

Will an enemy still drop EXP if it gets transformed into a Harmless Takodachi?